# Filling Pandas columns with lists of unequal lengths

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I am having trouble filling Pandas dataframes with values from lists of unequal lengths.

`nx_lists_into_df` is a list of numpy arrays.

I get the following error:

> ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index

The code is below:

```
# Column headers
df_cols = ["f1","f2"]

# Create one dataframe fror each sheet
df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=df_cols)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=df_cols)

# Create list of dataframes to iterate through
df_list = [df1, df2]

# Lists to be put into the dataframes   
nx_lists_into_df = [[array([0, 1, 3, 4, 7]),
                     array([2, 5, 6, 8])],
                    [array([0, 1, 2, 6, 7]),
                     array([3, 4, 5, 8])]]

# Loop through each sheet (i.e. each round of k folds)
for df, test_index_list in zip_longest(df_list, nx_lists_into_df):
    counter = -1
    # Loop through each column in that sheet (i.e. each fold)
    for col in df_cols:
        print(col)
        counter += 1
        # Add 1 to each index value to start indexing at 1
        df[col] = test_index_list[counter] + 1
```

Thank you for your help.

Edit: This is how the result should hopefully look:-

```
print(df1)

   f1   f2
0   0    2
1   1    5
2   3    6
3   4    8
4   7  NaN

print(df2)

   f1   f2
0   0    3
1   1    4
2   2    5
3   6    8
4   7  NaN
```

Comment: What should the final result look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We'll leverage `pd.Series` to attach an appropriate index and will allow us to use the `pd.DataFrame` constructor without complaining of unequal lengths.

```
df1, df2 = (
    pd.DataFrame(dict(zip(df_cols, map(pd.Series, d))))
    for d in nx_lists_into_df
)
```

---

```
print(df1)

   f1   f2
0   0  2.0
1   1  5.0
2   3  6.0
3   4  8.0
4   7  NaN
```

---

```
print(df2)

   f1   f2
0   0  3.0
1   1  4.0
2   2  5.0
3   6  8.0
4   7  NaN
```

---

**Setup**

```
from numpy import array

nx_lists_into_df = [[array([0, 1, 3, 4, 7]),
                     array([2, 5, 6, 8])],
                    [array([0, 1, 2, 6, 7]),
                     array([3, 4, 5, 8])]]

# Column headers
df_cols = ["f1","f2"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could predefine the size of your DataFrames (by setting the index range to the length of the longest column you want to add [or any size bigger than the longest column]) like so:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=df_cols, index=range(5))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=df_cols, index=range(5))

print(df1)
    f1   f2
0  NaN  NaN
1  NaN  NaN
2  NaN  NaN
3  NaN  NaN
4  NaN  NaN
```

(df2 is the same)

The DataFrame will be filled with NaNs automatically.

Then you use .loc to access each entry separately like so:

```
for x in range(len(nx_lists_into_df)):
    for col_idx, y in enumerate(nx_lists_into_df[x]):
        df_list[x].loc[range(len(y)), df_cols[col_idx]] = y


print(df1)
  f1   f2
0  0    2
1  1    5
2  3    6
3  4    8
4  7  NaN

print(df2)
  f1   f2
0  0    3
1  1    4
2  2    5
3  6    8
4  7  NaN
```

The first loop iterates over the first dimension of your array (or the number of DataFrames you want to create).

The second loop iterates over the column values  for the DataFrame, where y are the values for the current column and df_cols[col_idx] is the respective column (f1 or f2).

Since the row & col indices are the same size as y, you don't get the length mismatch.

Also check out the [enumerate(iterable, start=0)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=enumerate#enumerate) function to get around those "counter" variables.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, this is possible via `pd.concat`.

But see [@pir's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49140957/9209546) for an extendable version.

```
# Lists to be put into the dataframes   
nx_lists_into_df = [[array([0, 1, 3, 4, 7]),
                     array([2, 5, 6, 8])],
                    [array([0, 1, 2, 6, 7]),
                     array([3, 4, 5, 8])]]

df1 = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame({'A': nx_lists_into_df[0][0]}),
                 pd.DataFrame({'B': nx_lists_into_df[0][1]})],
                 axis=1)

#    A    B
# 0  0  2.0
# 1  1  5.0
# 2  3  6.0
# 3  4  8.0
# 4  7  NaN

df2 = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame({'C': nx_lists_into_df[1][0]}),
                 pd.DataFrame({'D': nx_lists_into_df[1][1]})],
                 axis=1)

#    C    D
# 0  0  3.0
# 1  1  4.0
# 2  2  5.0
# 3  6  8.0
# 4  7  NaN
```

Comment: Yes! That's exactly right. Although I have shortened the number of dataframes and lists to make it more understandable. Is there a way to iterate through many more?

Comment: you could turn `[pd.DataFrame({'C': nx_lists_into_df[1][0]}), pd.DataFrame({'D': nx_lists_into_df[1][1]})]` into a list comprehension, but you will need to be careful with column names and indices in your list of arrays.